# MySQL count records and using a weight

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database called "games" that records information of each game thats played (how many players, how long the game was, when the game was, etc).

Right now I query this information to simply just find how many games were played each day (i put the query I have below).

I am trying to modify so that it will "weight" each game based on how many players participated in the game (numPlayersEnd).

ie if a game has 2 players, it should count as 1.0 games. If a game has 3 players, it should count as 1.5 games. and if a game has 4 players it should count as 2.0 games.

Does anyone know how to do this in a SQL query? or will I have to do this with java after getting the query result?

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(datetimeStart, '%H') AS hour,
DATE_FORMAT(datetimeStart, '%d') AS day,
DATE_FORMAT(datetimeStart, '%m') AS month,
DATE_FORMAT(datetimeStart, '%Y') AS year, 
COUNT(*) AS count 

FROM 
games 

WHERE 
numPlayersEnd IS NOT NULL  AND datetimeStart >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

GROUP BY 
DATE_FORMAT(datetimeStart, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not grouping by the `hour`, so there is no reason to include that in the `select`.  Actually, your aggregation columns in the `select` *should be* identical to the columns in the `group by`.  But, that is not how you phrased the question.

Second, it seems like you just want to sum `numPlayersEnd / 2`.  That is easy enough:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetimeStart, '%d') AS day,
       DATE_FORMAT(datetimeStart, '%m') AS month,
       DATE_FORMAT(datetimeStart, '%Y') AS year, 
       COUNT(*) AS count ,
       SUM(numPlayersEnd / 2) as weighted_count
FROM games 
WHERE numPlayersEnd IS NOT NULL  AND datetimeStart >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY  DATE_FORMAT(datetimeStart, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: ah thank you so much. It turns out to be a lot more simple than I thought itd be. I didnt know there was a sum function that worked like that.